# Dropdown under listview builder under dropdown under listviewbuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a listview builder and have a dropdown in each element it's in an expansion tile widget and under expansion tile have a dropdown as I said now if I select dropdown value then a listview builder creates that number of the list if I click on that list element its shows a dialog has a dropdown if the select value on that it reflects on first listview builder 2nd element generated list by dropdown in first element dropdown.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class dynamicList2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _dynamicList2State createState() => _dynamicList2State();
}

class _dynamicList2State extends State<dynamicList2> {
  List roomAvailable = [];
  List adultList = [];
  List<String> selectedItemValue = List<String>();
  List<String> selectAdults = List<String>();
  List<TextEditingController> priceController = [];

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> hello = {
    "room_list": [
      {
        "roomtype": "bedroom",
        "room_id": "1",
        "available": [
          {"value": 1, "no_room": 1},
          {"value": 2, "no_room": 2},
          {"value": 3, "no_room": 3},
          {"value": 4, "no_room": 4}
        ],
        "adultList": [
          {"value": 1, "adult": 1},
          {"value": 2, "adult": 2},
          {"value": 3, "adult": 3},
          {"value": 4, "adult": 4}
        ]
      },
      {
        "roomtype": "premium delux room",
        "room_id": "2",
        "available": [
          {"value": 1, "no_room": 1},
          {"value": 2, "no_room": 2},
          {"value": 3, "no_room": 3},
          {"value": 4, "no_room": 4},
          {"value": 5, "no_room": 5}
        ],
        "adultList": [
          {"value": 1, "adult": 1},
          {"value": 2, "adult": 2},
          {"value": 3, "adult": 3}
        ]
      },
      {
        "roomtype": "myroomType",
        "room_id": "3",
        "available": [
          {"value": 1, "no_room": 1},
          {"value": 2, "no_room": 2},
        ],
        "adultList": [
          {"value": 1, "adult": 1},
          {"value": 2, "adult": 2},
          {"value": 3, "adult": 3},
          {"value": 3, "adult": 4},
          {"value": 3, "adult": 5}
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  Widget reservationBox() {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: hello["room_list"].length,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
        roomAvailable = hello["room_list"][index]["available"];
        // print(roomAvailable);
        adultList = hello["room_list"][index]["adultList"];
        print(adultList);
        selectAdults.add("1");
        priceController.add(new TextEditingController());
        selectedItemValue.add("1");
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    color: Colors.white),
                child: ListTileTheme(
                  dense: true,
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 109, 112, 1.0)),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    title: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(hello["room_list"][index]["roomtype"],
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 109, 112, 1.0))),
                        Text(
                          hello["room_list"][index]["available"]
                              .length
                              .toString(),
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 109, 112, 1.0)),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Divider(
                        thickness: 1.0,
                        height: 1.0,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      expansionData2(
                          index, hello["room_list"][index]["roomtype"])
                      /*expansionData()*/
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Widget expansionData2(index, String val) {
    // print(index);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 6.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text("Add Rooms",
                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                      fontSize: 15.5,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(2, 15, 67, 1))),
              Container(
                width: 90,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                  value: selectedItemValue[index].toString(),
                  items: roomAvailable.map((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        item['no_room'].toString(),
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                      value: item['value'].toString(),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedItemValue[index] = value;
                      print(selectedItemValue[index].toString());
                      print(selectedItemValue);
                    });
                  },
                  hint: Text(
                    'Select',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        dynamicBox3(index, val),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget dynamicBox3(hello, String val) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: int.parse(selectedItemValue[hello]),
          itemBuilder: (context, myindex) {
            myindex = myindex + 1;
            return Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 5),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("Room $myindex",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 13.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(2, 15, 67, 1))),
                      InkWell(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                          size: 22,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(2, 15, 67, 1),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          dialogBox(myindex, val);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  void dialogBox(myindex, val) {
    showDialog(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Dialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Room -$myindex :',
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 109, 112, 1.0)),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Adults :',
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                            fontSize: 17,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(2, 15, 67, 1)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
                        height: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10, right: 3, bottom: 6),
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0),
                            ),
                            value: selectAdults[myindex].toString(),
                            items: adultList.map((item) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: Text(
                                  item['adult'].toString(),
                                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                      color: Colors.black54),
                                ),
                                value: item['value'].toString(),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              selectAdults[myindex] = value;
                              print(selectAdults[myindex]);
                            },
                            hint: Text(
                              'Select',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Save',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      context: context,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ListView2"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 26),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 28),
                        child: Divider(
                          thickness: 1.0,
                          height: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 109, 112, 1.0),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 13.0, vertical: 20),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text('Room Type',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: Colors.white)),
                                    Text('Available',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: Colors.white)),
                                    Text('Details',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: Colors.white)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              reservationBox(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```